# Execute the query with additional option (parallelism)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, nhibernate, queryover

Currently NHibernate is just transforming my queryover code to SQL statements. Problem is that my SQL Server is executing a specific query with *parallelism*. Sadly that twitch in sql makes the query very very very slow.

I know that you have to add `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` in sql to disable parallelism, but how do I tell NHibernate to do this for that single query?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to set the *max degree of parallelism* on your SQL server to 1 (or what ever your logical cores are) you are having this problem probably because the server is trying to do more parallelism than it can handle.